# If temperature means kinetic energy, is that proportional to force?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, energy, temperature

How is there so much pressure at the bottom of the ocean and therefore a greater force transmitted by collision, even though the temperature remains constant ? Shouldn't greater pressure and therefore greater molecular acceleration create a higher temperature ?

Comment: The pressure at the bottom of the ocean is not due to an increase in molecular activity. It is due to the weight of the water above.

Comment: @BobD post it as a answer if you have the time ok?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but I think if you read my answer to this question you'll have the answer to yours. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/757074/liquid-pressure-at-the-atomic-level/757078#757078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of incorrect hidden assumptions in the question that are unfortunately quite common. First:

> pressure at the bottom of the ocean ... force transmitted by collision

At the bottom of the ocean is water, which is a liquid and not a gas. It is not much like a real gas and even less like an ideal gas. In particular, in a liquid the molecules interact quite strongly with each other, which violates one of the primary assumptions of the ideal gas. The do not merely collide with the container in brief isolated collisions, but they push each other almost continuously.

Treating the interaction of water molecules at the bottom of the ocean as ideal gas collisions is nearly guaranteed to produce mistaken conclusions. In a liquid the intermolecular interactions should be thought of as continuous rather than as collisions.

> greater pressure and therefore greater molecular acceleration

Second, even for an ideal gas this "therefore" does not follow. Let's depart from thinking about the ocean and just think about a standard ideal gas. Say that we have one mole of nitrogen gas at standard temperature and pressure. Now, that corresponds to a specific volume, which we can calculate using the ideal gas law. Suppose that we isothermally compress that gas to a smaller volume. By the ideal gas law, if the pressure doubles then the volume halves.

Now, it has a greater pressure, but not a greater molecular acceleration. What has changed is not the amount of acceleration each molecule undergoes, but the frequency of collisions. The volume is smaller so it takes less time to cross from one wall of the container to the opposite. The collisions are not more energetic, but they are more frequent.

The mistaken assumption is that increased pressure implies greater molecular acceleration. It is possible to get increased pressure in an ideal gas either through greater molecular acceleration (increasing temperature) or through more frequent collisions (reducing volume).

Comment: I think i'm start gett it . But  I have some questions yet .How this pressure is transmitted ?its trough molecular colisions . Some way the energy of colisions are accumulating in deeper ocean and this manner reducing hidrogen bonds ?

Comment: @GabrielRochaFurtado for a liquid the molecules are not experiencing discrete collisions. They are continually interacting. Thinking of it as a collision is just going to give you a wrong picture. Think of it more like a rugby scrum. There is a lot of pushing and jostling and motion, but not discrete collisions.

Answer (score 0):

> If temperature means kinetic energy, is that proportional to force?

No. But an *increase* in kinetic energy (and thus an increase in temperature) can result from *work* done by a force.

In the case of compressing a fluid (gas or liquid) that work can be described by

$$W=\int_{V1}^{V2}PdV$$

Unlike a gas, where compression work can result in an increase in temperature,  water is relatively incompressible ($dV\approx 0$) due to the repulsive forces between water molecules. Thus virtually no compression work would be done on the water below by the pressure of the water above that would theoretically increase its temperature.

In short, the increase in pressure at the bottom of the ocean is due to the weight of the water above, and not due to increased molecular activity.

Hope this helps.